# gridview PageIndexChanging issue

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, page-index-changed

I am trying to to loop through a dataset's value through the rows in a gridview and color in the text if that row matches.

The code below works however whenever I change the page through the `PageIndexChanging` and this function is ran again, the coloring doesn't work anymore. It still loops through the gridview if there is a match but the effects are not shown.

```
        --variable initialization class instantiation--

        --code to connect to db here--

        mySQLCommand.CommandText = "SELECT ..."
        mySQLAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(mySQLCommand)
        mySQLAdapter.Fill(myDataset)
        Me.MainPageGridView.DataSource = myDataset
        Me.MainPageGridView.DataBind()

        mySQLCommand.CommandText = "SELECT ... The ID's to be matched"
        mySQLAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(mySQLCommand)
        mySQLAdapter.Fill(myDatasetNew)
        Me.MainPageGridView.DataSource = myDatasetNew

       For Each dataRow In myDataset.Tables(0).Rows
            thisID = dataRow("ID").ToString
            For Each gvRow In Me.MainPageGridView.Rows
                If gvRow.Cells(2).Text = thisID Then
                    For column = 0 To 14 Step 1
                        gvRow.Cells(column).ForeColor = Drawing.Color.RosyBrown
                    Next
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        Next
```

Comment: why are you binding both datasets to same grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use `MainPageGridView_RowDataBound` event to match the id? I have re-factored your original code to something like below, please check and let me know if it works:

```
'In DataBind or some other method
        'Load(myDataSet)
        mySQLCommand.CommandText = "SELECT ..."
        mySQLAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(mySQLCommand)
        mySQLAdapter.Fill(myDataset)

        'Load myDatasetNew and bind it to grid
        mySQLCommand.CommandText = "SELECT ... The ID's to be matched"
        mySQLAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(mySQLCommand)
        mySQLAdapter.Fill(myDatasetNew)
        Me.MainPageGridView.DataSource = myDatasetNew
        Me.MainPageGridView.DataBind()
```

and perform id matching in

```
Protected Sub MainPageGridView_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles MainPageGridView.RowDataBound
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            Dim id As String = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ID") 'The name of ID column in "myDatasetNew"

            Dim dv As System.Data.DataView = myDataset.Tables(0).DefaultView
            dv.RowFilter = "ID = " & id

            If dv.Count > 0 Then 'id matches
                'Change foreclor of entire row
                e.Row.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.RosyBrown
            End If

        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but where do I place the loading of `myDataset`?

Comment: anywhere before loading myDatasetNew

Comment: I wasn't able to get it to work with your method so I altered a little of my code to fit into rowdatabound and it now works.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to do your data comparison in the [GridView.RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event.